# Почему функция возвращает undefined если переменная не пустая?

Tags: node.js

```
var menus = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Список пользователей',
    Parent_ID: 0,
    url: '/list-user'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Добавить пользователя',
    Parent_ID: 0,
    url: '/add-user'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Заявка на редактирование сайта',
    Parent_ID: 0,
    url: '/report-site'
  }
]

let q = filterMenu(menus,request.session.login);
console.log(q);
function filterMenu(menus,login){
    const user = ['Заявка на редактирование сайта'];
    models.user.user.findOne({where: {login: login}})
    .then(us=>{
        if(us.privilege == 1){
            return menus.filter(n => user.includes(n.name));
        }else{
            return menus;
        }
    })
}
```

Если внутри функции запихнуть в переменную и вывести ее - все ок, но если я пытаюсь вывести q - пишет андефайнед. В чем дело?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что return относится к промису .findOne() а не к функции !

Comment: и как тут тогда быть? В плане как мне вернуть? Если я запишу все в переменную то как я ее верну, если после блока findOne я напишу возврат - переменная вернется пустой ведь

Comment: Добавляем async function filterMenu() // объявим переменную X в которую будем запоминать значение из return, еще одну переменную чтобы не потерять контекст self = this; Добавляем await models.user.user.findOne() // присваиваем self.X = вместо return